# Program two UISliders to not exceed each others values

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

This is the valueChanged voids for my two UISliders. Their function is to set the minimum and maximum price for objects. What I cannot figure out it how to make them not exceed each others  values.

So if `minPrisSlider.value = 100`, it should not be possible to drag the maxPrisSlider below 100 and opposite.

```
- (void)minValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(minPrisSlider.value + 0.5); // Round the number.
[minPrisSlider setValue:index animated:NO];

int progressAsInt =(int)(minPrisSlider.value + 0.5f);
NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d,-",progressAsInt];
minPrisText.text = newText;
}

- (void)maxValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{

NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(maxPrisSlider.value + 0.5); // Round the number.
[maxPrisSlider setValue:index animated:NO];

int progressAsInt =(int)(maxPrisSlider.value + 0.5f);
NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d,-",progressAsInt];
maxPrisText.text = newText;

}
```

I have tried adding

`[minPrisSlider setMaximumValue:maxPrisSlider.value];` in `maxValueChanged`

and

`[maxPrisSlider setMinimumValue:minPrisSlider.value];` in `minValueChanged`

but it returns strange results...

Got some working solution for this?

Comment: what does "it returns strange results" mean?

Comment: "The thing is, the slider's thumb position is proportional to its maximum/minimum value." as Snaker said. Moving minPrisSlider thumb made maxPrisSlider thumb moving opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, the slider's thumb position is proportional to its maximum/minimum value. So setting the maximum/minimum value shouldn't do
In your case, you should try this :

```
if ([minPrisSlider value] > [maxPrisSlider value])
  [minPrisSlider setValue:[maxPrisSlider value]];
```

And reverse it for the max slider. Don't forget to set the continuous value :

```
[minPrisSlider setContinuous:YES];
```